# Create site collection with my own master page

Tags: 2010, master-page, custom-masterpage

When user want to create new site collection in SharePoint 2010. That site collection (Team Site) must create with my customized master page as default master page. And also I need to activate some feature by default.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can create custom site definition and then create site from that site collection .

Comment: What Bhaskar said, just create a new site collection from scratch, activate the features you need and set your custom master page as default and save the site as template. HOWEVER, activating the publishing infrastructure won't work in other site collections created from the template and is not supported by MS.

Comment: Oh, but i am trying to activate publishing feature only. What i can do?????

Comment: [Hope this will help your query](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Branding-e73dffa0)

Answer (score 0):

The Publishing feature does not support the Save Site as Template option. It is necessary to create site definition templates for site collections on which Publishing feature is to be activated.
You can also achieve this by feature stapling. [Link for reference](http://kmsnet.blogspot.in/2011/07/activate-publishing-feature-in.html)
Below link have detailed explanation , hope this will help.
[this is what exactly you are looking for](http://info.akgroup.com/blog-0/bid/61658/Automatically-Turning-on-the-Publishing-Feature-on-a-SharePoint-Team-Site)